# this.props.history.push() не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

При переходе на /admin не работает this.props.history.push('/admin/signIn'). Когда ввожу роут в ручную, всё отлично переходит. А когда ввожу /admin, вместо редиректа получаю ошибку:
 [image: ошибка в браузере]

Полагаю, что всё из-за этого ворнинга, но исправить его не удаётся[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

src/index.js

```
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Admin from './components/Admin';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Reducers from './reducers';

import authGuard from './components/HOCs/authGuard';

const jwt = localStorage.getItem('JWT');

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = jwt;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {createStore(Reducers, {
        auth: {
            token: jwt,
            isAuthenticated: jwt ? true : false
        }
    }, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App> 
                <Route exact path = '/' component = { Main } />
                <Route exact path = '/admin' component = { authGuard(Admin) } />
                <Route exact path = '/admin/signIn' component = { SignIn } />
                <Route exact path = '/signUp' component = { SignUp } />
            </App>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>, 
document.querySelector('#root'))

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

authGuard.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default (OriginalComponent) => {
    class MixedComponent extends Component {
        checkAuth() {
            if(!this.props.isAuth && !this.props.jwt) {
                console.log(this.props.history)
                this.props.history.push('/admin/signIn'); //а вот и он
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.checkAuth();
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            this.checkAuth();
        }


        render() {
            return <OriginalComponent {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            isAuth: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
            jwt: state.auth.token
        }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(MixedComponent);
}
```

component/Admin.js:

```
class Admin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {   
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return(<div></div>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, actions),
    reduxForm({form: 'admin'})
)(Admin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо передать роутеру объект browserHistory в src/index.js

```
...
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
...
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
...
<BrowserRouter
    history={browserHistory}
>
...
```

Comment: неа, не помогло :(

Comment: а `console.log(this.props.history)` в вашем коде выдает что-то?

Comment: у меня получилось исправить это, сделал в authGuard.js render() return (props) => <OriginalComponent {...props}/>, но теперь новый ворнинг "Functions are not valid as a React child."

Comment: похоже в authGuard не передаются props, поскольку это не компонент, а функция, у которой только один параметр "ОригинальныйКомпонент"

Comment: выдаёт объект history {length: 4, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}

Comment: props то передаются, онож проверят на авторизацию, и входит в этот if с history.push только когда пользователь не авторизован